# How to refresh uilabel text in a uiview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, uibutton

There's a subclass of UIView called HiView

HiView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface HiView : UIView
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *textcontent;
@end
```

HiView.m

```
@implementation HiView
@synthesize textcontent;
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
    textcontent = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    [self addSubview:textcontent];
}
return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    //some codes
}
@end
```

In a UIViewController, there's a UIScrollView

```
@interface TheVC ()
@property (nonatomic, retain) HiView *hiview;
@end
//some codes
UIScrollView *scrollview = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
[self.view addSubview:scrollview];
for (int index=0; index<5; index++) {
    _hiview = [[HiView alloc] init];
    _hiview.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width * index, 50, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [scrollview addSubview:_hiview];
}
```

and there's a button in this UIViewController, when I click it, the UILabel in hiview should be change, and now I use `_hiview.textcontent.text = "changed";`, but it seems not work, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should create an array to hold all the hiviews and change it anywhere , as your current implementation only references the last view , the view you created as instance variable can't hold a reference to all the views as it's a single object , which is here

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) HiView *hiview;
```

// so create an array

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray*allViews
}
```

// add every newly created hiview to it

```
for (int index=0; index<5; index++) {
    HiView*hiview = [[HiView alloc] init];
    hiview.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width * index, 50, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [scrollview addSubview:hiview];
    [allViews addObject:hiview];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use tags to hold reference to your views 
And remove the hiview property from your .h

```
for (int index=0; index<5; index++){
HiView *hiview = [[HiView alloc] init];
hiview.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width * index, 50, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
hiview.tag = (index + 1);
[scrollview addSubview:hiview];
}
```

Then you would say

```
For (int i=1; i<=5; i++){
((HiView *)[scrollview viewWithTag:i]).textcontent.string = @"something";
 }
```